# Python relative imports that skip intermediate folder in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import, python-module, relative-import

I am trying to understand the code in someone else's mixed-language repository (part of a large, complicated code base). The directory structure is like this:

```
module_A/
    python/
        __init__.py
        script_A.py
        script_B.py
    other/
        other_scripts.cxx
```

The contents of `__init__.py` are

```py
__version__ = '1.0.0'
```

The code has relative imports from `script_B.py` to `script_A.py` like the following:

```py
from module_A import script_B
```

Note that the intermediate directory `python` has been skipped. I know that the code runs, so python itself does not have a problem parsing this import statement. However, in VSCode, pylint throws a fit:

```
No name 'script_B' in module 'module_A'
```

I would really like to resolve this error so that (a) I can use VSCode tools to help myself understand how the code works (e.g., function definitions on hover) and (b) I can more easily contribute to the code in the future (e.g., with code autocomplete).

Can someone explain the following?

1. What is going on here? I have never seen relative imports in python that skip an intermediate directory before.
2. How can I resolve the error in VSCode to recover the usual quality-of-life tools?

Comment: Might be a problem that you opend vscode with root directory and the scripts expect the python folder to be root? Have you tried opening python as root dir?

Comment: I'm working across multiple repositories at once, so I'd like to keep the VSCode workspace open at a high level if possible

Comment: These are _absolute_ imports - somehow script_A is added to the module_A namespace. How is the code run?

Comment: Ah that is entirely possible; there is some environment setup that must be run before anything works

Answer (score 0):

`script_A.py` is in the folder python. If your workspace is the parent directory of `module_A`, you have to use the codes like `from module_A.python import script_B`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question; the code, as written, works at runtime, so somehow the module is found correctly. I would like the imports to be correctly reflected in VS Code

Comment: @book_kees Can setting the `script_B` path in the `.env` file and importing it directly in debug mode meet your needs? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_envfile